# Android - "Resources don't contain package for resource number"

Tags: android, debugging

My android application has several warnings of the following form when I run it in the emulator:

> "Resources don't contain package for resource number <Hex Address>"

How can I fix these warnings? In particular, is there an easy way to find out what the hex address refers to?

Comment: It's coming from frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be coming from the emulator, but it is now working fine, so these aren't errors. Still curious why they are occuring though

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but isn't the hex address from R.java?
If so, you should be able to identify the resource pretty easily.

Comment: I checked, but they aren't in R.java